# How to find array element in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, search

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "enter numbers ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "NUMBER : ";
    int key;
    cin >> key;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == key) {
            cout << arr[i] << endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "nothing";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code should take 10 integer value and store them in the array. After user gives another number it should check whether the number is already present in array or not.
I have tried a lot different approach but still stuck at output.

Comment: You can just use [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: `auto it = std::find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), key);`. Then check `it` against the end of `arr` to determine if the `key` was found. Also, make sure you check whether the input was successful before using the vamues read!

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean when you say "but still stuck at output."?

Answer (score 2):

So you can only tell if the number of not in the array **after** you have checked all the numbers. So outputting `"nothing"` inside the loop is wrong. It needs to be after the loop. The simple way to do this is to use a `bool` variable which starts out as `false` but is set to `true` when you find the key. That way if it's still `false` at the end of the loop you know you didn't find the key anywhere in the array.

Like this

```
bool found_it = false;
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==key)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
        found_it = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found_it) // did we find anything?
    cout<<"nothing"<<endl;
```